# Java Input string "-10" under radix 16

Tags: java, parsing

I am coding a basic program that reads Computer instructions and I have having issues with the parsing.  For example, when reading one line of a file I am looking for a number.  If it is a digit then I put it into a char array such as -10. For example DEC -10 (9 being the starting index because it is where the number is placed). When I parse, I get the following issue Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-10 " under radix 16.
When I pass in my own string that contains a number in it, I get no issues outputting.

```
                    char store[] = new char[4];
                    for (int i = 9; i <= lineRead.length() -1; i ++) {
                        char ch = lineRead.charAt(i);

                        if (ch == '-' || Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                            if(store.length == i - 8) {
                                store = Arrays.copyOf(store, store.length +1);
                            }
                            store[i-9] = ch;
                        }

                        else if (ch == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }

                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    value = String.valueOf(store);
                    hexConv = Integer.parseInt(new String(value));
```

Comment: `For input string: "-10 "` <- Do you see that extra space at the end of your String? That is your problem. edit: quickest fix is to just call the `trim()` function on your string before you pass it to the `parseInt` method.

Comment: Sorry my brain is kind of fried atm, how do I remove the space from the string